# Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, version 9.0.30739.1 SP, DLL build errors

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am modifying an existing DLL that was built a long time ago and has been used.  I'm adding new functionality to the DLL which requires the use of the Echelon Lonworks OpenLDV library to replace an old 32 bit solution.  The OpenLDV adds support for both 32bit and 64bit installations.

When I include the header ldv32.h, I now get a lot of compiler errors:

```
    Error   213 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ContextRecord'   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\winnt.h   5545    FsLonPlayer
    Error   214 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\winnt.h   5545    FsLonPlayer
    Error   215 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\winnt.h   5545    FsLonPlayer
    Error   216 error C2065: 'PCONTEXT' : undeclared identifier c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\winnt.h   11263   FsLonPlayer
    Error   217 error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'ContextRecord'   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\winnt.h   11264   FsLonPlayer
    Error   219 error C2182: 'RtlCaptureContext' : illegal use of type 'void'   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\winnt.h   11264   FsLonPlayer
    Error   220 error C2491: 'RtlCaptureContext' : definition of dllimport data not allowed c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\winnt.h   11264   FsLonPlayer
    Error   221 error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\winnt.h   11264   FsLonPlayer
    Error   222 error C3861: '__readfsdword': identifier not found  c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\winnt.h   12935   FsLonPlayer
```

I've spent a lot of time searching around for a solution, changing the "Create/Use Precompiled Header" option to:

```
    Not Using Precompiled Headers
    Create Precompiled Header (/Yc)
    Use Precompiled Header (/Yu)
```

After each change I cleaned the project and rebuilt but the result is the same.

What is the problem?

Comment: Just a wild guess here.. Have you tried including `windows.h`?

Comment: I didn't change the original code, just included the new header.  However, having just inserted windows.h above ldv32.h it now compiles without error, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Saliesh for the comment, I did have the headers:

```
    #include <WinDef.h>
    #include <winnt.h>

    #include "ldv32.h"
```

After replacing with

```
    #include <windows.h>

    #include "ldv32.h"
```

It now compiles without errors.